# Trying to translate object

Tags: opengl, c

I'm trying to tranlate a matrix by xy but the result is strange. can someone help me translate and rotate the matrix properly?

```
void Transform_Update(Transform *transform, GLfloat depth)
{
    Matrix4_SetToIdentity(transform->transformationMatrix);
    Matrix4_Set(transform->transformationMatrix, 0, 3, transform->position->x);
    Matrix4_Set(transform->transformationMatrix, 1, 3, transform->position->y);
    Matrix4_Set(transform->transformationMatrix, 2, 3, depth);
}
```

Here is my Matrix set value.

```
void Matrix4_Set(Matrix4 *m, GLuint line, GLuint column, GLfloat value)
{
    m->data[line * 4 + column] = value;
}
```

Here is where I make the matrix to the identity matrix

```
void Matrix4_SetToIdentity(Matrix4 *m)
{
    GLfloat data[16] = { 1, 0, 0, 0,
                         0, 1, 0, 0,
                         0, 0, 1, 0,
                         0, 0, 0, 1 };

    memcpy(m->data, data, sizeof(GLfloat) * 16 );
}
```

This is where I render my mesh and update shader values

```
void Renderer_Render(Renderer *renderer, Camera *camera)
{
    glUseProgram(renderer->shader->id);

    Transform_Update(renderer->gameObject->transform, renderer->depth);

    GLint location = Shader_GetUniformLocation(renderer->shader, "transformationMatrix");
    glProgramUniformMatrix4fv(renderer->shader->id, location, 1, GL_FALSE, renderer->gameObject->transform->transformationMatrix->data);

    GLint location2 = Shader_GetUniformLocation(renderer->shader, "projectionMatrix");
    glProgramUniformMatrix4fv(renderer->shader->id, location2, 1, GL_FALSE, camera->projectionMatrix);

    GLint location3 = Shader_GetUniformLocation(renderer->shader, "viewMatrix");
    glProgramUniformMatrix4fv(renderer->shader->id, location3, 1, GL_FALSE, camera->viewMatrix);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderer->texture->id);

    Mesh_Render(renderer->mesh);
}
```

Here is my shader transforming the vertices :

```
#version 400 core

in vec3 position;
in vec2 textureCoords;

out vec2 pass_textureCoords;

uniform mat4 transformationMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;

void main(void) { 

    vec4 worldPosition = transformationMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    vec4 positionRelativeToCamera = viewMatrix * worldPosition;

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * positionRelativeToCamera;
    pass_textureCoords = textureCoords;
}
```

Here is how I get the view and projection matrix :

```
void Camera_Render(Screen *screen, Camera *camera)
{
    glClearColor(camera->backgroundColor->red, camera->backgroundColor->green, camera->backgroundColor->blue, camera->backgroundColor->alpha);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glLoadIdentity();            
    glTranslatef(camera->transform->position->x, camera->transform->position->y, 0);
    glRotatef(camera->transform->angle, 0, 0, 1);

    glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, camera->projectionMatrix);
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, camera->viewMatrix);
}
```

The current output when I change X is this :

[image: The output seams to rotate...Not really...it's just wierd]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your matrices are row-major, whereas OpenGL expects column-major matrices. In your calls to `glProgramUniformMatrix4fv()`, you should  set the transpose parameter to `GL_TRUE`, like this:

```
glProgramUniformMatrix4fv(renderer->shader->id, location, 1, GL_TRUE, renderer->gameObject->transform->transformationMatrix->data);
```

Comment: bump…. I've changed it but now nothing is rendered. Do you know what is the problem?

Comment: Great! If you found it useful, don't forget to mark it as having solved your problem by clicking the green checkmark to the left.